# Class design - how to manage multiple thread responses

Tags: c#, multithreading, class

I need some help on how to best design a set of classes for managing a multithread C# app I am developing.
I have successfully created a ThreadContainer class that launches a series of Threads.
The Threads download financial data from specific websites. 
For each website passed they will open the same base url but with a different symbols. 
So there are # results equal to the number of symbols passed for each website.
Then depending on the website that was requested the Threads results have to treated in a different way...
Here is the simplified ThreadContainer code:

```
public class ThreadContainer
{
private int ConcurrentThreads;
private string Website;
public string URL;
private Queue SymQueue;

//Constructor
public ThreadContainer(string website, Queue symQueue)
{
   Website = website;
   SymQueue = symQueue;
}

//Start
public void start(int concurrent)
{
    ConcurrentThreads = concurrent;

    //Start the Concurrent Threads
    for (int ThreadNum = 1; ThreadNum <= ConcurrentThreads; ThreadNum++)
    {   
        //Get a symbol from the queue
        Sym = SymQueue.Dequeue().ToString(); 

        //Build the URL
        URL = string.Format(Constants.URL(Website), Sym);

        //Create a new Asynch thread 
        AsynchThread j = new AsynchThread(ThreadNum);

        //Start the AsyncThread class with the BackgoundWorker
        j.Start(Sym, URL);
    }
}

//Method called when the Backgroundworker thread has terminated 
private void AsynchThread1_JobCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the AsynchThread object
    AsynchThread j = (AsynchThread)sender;

        //Get the symbol name
        String Sym = j.Sym;

        //Get the result with the Webpage content
        RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs re = e as RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs;
        String result = re.Result.ToString();

        /* HERE EACH THREAD RETURNS THE WEBSITE CONTENT.
         * DEPENDING ON THE WEBSITE THAT WAS REQUESTED SEVERAL ACTIONS MAY BE EXECUTED.
        */
        switch(website)
        {
            case "WebsiteA":
                // With WebsiteA I would like to :
                // 1. extract the symbol data
                // 2. return the result for this symbol to the calling class.

            case "WebsiteB":
                // With WebsiteB I would like to:
                // 1. extract the symbol data (Webpage design is different from WebsiteA)
                // 2. store each symbol data in a database table

            case "WebsiteC":
                // With WebsiteB I would like to:
                // 1. extract the symbol data (Webpage design is different from WebsiteA and WebsiteB)
                // 2. put the results in a queue 

            case ...

            default:            
                return "";
        }        

        // Reuse the thread that has just completed
        //If there are items left in the queue...
        if (SymQueue.Count > 0)
            //...get the new Sym value...
            NewSym = SymQueue.Dequeue().ToString();

        //If NewSym is valid ...
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(NewSym))
        {
            //...build the URL...
            String NewURL = string.Format(Constants.URL(Website), NewSym);

            //...then restart the thread with the new parameters
            j.Start(NewSym, NewURL);
        }    
    }
}
```

I would like to know what is the best way to design the **AsynchThread1_JobCompleted**
method.
This method is called when each Thread has terminated and should carry out the following tasks:

1. get the webpage content
2. extract the data from the webpage
3. send the data back to the caller or save the data to a DB or insert the data in a queue.
4. check if the queue has still items and relaunch the thread with a new URL so it will open a new Webpage.

How can I design the method so I don't have to modify the code everytime I need to add a new website? 
Also, should I use the same AsynchThread that downloaded the page for extracting the data, save to the DB, etc... or is it better another thread for that?
I would like to have the ThreadContainer class following a kind of single-responsibility principle...

Thanks

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you targeting?

Comment: Maybe just Enqueue the result into an Queue<object> and then Dequeue it with master thread.

Answer (score 0):

In the EventArgs pass a delegate/action to a specific implementation which handles this site.

Or better isolate a class Site, where you put the url, and method to handle the specific work to be done with the data. Then pass Site in EventArgs for the thread, and call the specific method of that Site in the callback.

That way you are going to remove the `case` statement, and move the code where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I design the method so I don't have to modify the code
>   everytime I need to add a new website?

There is a problem with your design that makes this difficult.  Based on the website, you want to perform different actions after you have received the data, so your post-processing *depends* on the website.  Your best case is to use a pattern that makes this more flexible, so your code maintenance is low.  But you haven't stated in what cases you want to do this, as you said:

> send the data back to the caller or save the data to a DB or insert the data in a queue.

What is the logic necessary needed to do this?  What is this based on?  It's hard to deduce from your code which has multiple responsibilities.  You need to abstract away these portions of your code.

What you could have is:

Use a factory pattern to create an object to process your request.  A request in your case is simply an object with a url and a queue of symbols to process, maybe something like this:

```
interface ISymbolRequest
{
    string Url;
    Queue<string> Symbols;
}
```

and a processor maybe something like this:

```
abstract class SymbolProcessor
{
    protected ISymbolRequest _Request;
    public SymbolProcessor(ISymbolRequest request)
    {
        _Request = request;
    }
    public abstract void GetSymbolData();
    public abstract void PostProcessSymbolData();
}
```

Use a factory pattern to create an object that processes the result of that request, which in your case would put it back in a queue, database etc.

I would also recommend using the Task Parallel Libraries (TPL) since you are using .NET 4.0.  This makes your code easier to read and wraps up a lot of complexities.  You can also do great stuff such as cancellations, continuations, etc.  You can get started [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the factory pattern, it looks interesting. Actually the website variable is passed to the ThreadContainer class that is the class launching all Threads. So the website is known BEFORE any Thread is generated. This is an example of how I launch the ThreadContainer: ThreadContainer tc = new ThreadContainer("Earnings", SymQueue);

Comment: @Forna: I do realize you know the website.  It might be best in your case to have a `Processor` class that knows how to interpret the data for each type of `ISymbolRequest` -- that's what I was getting at.